# Is it OK to make all CSS sizes in EM and then modify html size with @Media queries?

Tags: css

I'm fiddling around with CSS on our website.
My understanding is that EM is based on document size.
So I can set that by setting the font-size of the HTML tag, right?

If I define all of our *font-size*'s in EM:

```
h2 { font-size:1.2em ;}
h3 { font-size: .975em;}
h4 {    font-size: .75em;}
```

When I change the html {font-size: .5em} they all change as i'd expect.
So, all of the above basically get sized down by 50% when the  html tag gets changed by an @media query.

```
@media screen and  (max-width: 400px) {
    .aphasia1rightbar {padding-left:0px}
    .homepage-url-field {display:none}
    html {
         font-size: .5em;}
}
```

But, I'm no CSS wizard, despite my LinkedIn profile to the contrary.
Am I missing something?
Anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: you better go for fixed sizes for **HTML** tag, and if you don't wish to worry about IE, then go for **rem** units inspite of em

Comment: @Deepak `rem` units are different from `em` units. Both are appropriate in different scenarios; one is not necessarily a replacement for the other in all cases.

Comment: `em`  refers to the font-size of the parent element. So if you go `div { font-size: 0.9em; }` and start to *nest* `div`s, you're in a world of trouble...

Comment: @connexo part of the goal of my approach is to minimize font-size tags, so no plans to set a size for the Div, although I guess if I nested the other tags (h1, h2) I might have a problem, although I tested that and the text rendered the same size in: <h1>H1 nesting H1
 <h1>H1</h1></h1>

Comment: That may very well be because your nesting creates invalid HTML. That's actually why I chose the `div` example. Try to nest a `.class` definition that involves font-size defined in `em`.